# In PHP, Is it possible to extract a twitter status from a string that has surrounding BBCode?

Tags: php, regex

I basicly have the following string

```
$string = 'Blah blah blah [url]https://twitter.com/NBCBlacklist/status/776165827104026624[/url] blah blah';
```

Im trying to do a preg_replace on this $string to make the output say

```
Blah blah blah TWITTER Link blah blah
```

So far I have this non-working line in my code

```
$string = preg_replace("/^https?:\/\/twitter\.com\/(?:#!\/)?(\w+)\/status(es)?\/(\d+)$/","TWITTER Link $1",$string);
```

Any ideas??

Comment: bbcode is just text. you can do whatever you want to the text...

Comment: What does "non-working" mean?

Comment: @Chris basicly "non-working" means that my php code above wont actually replace a twitter status URL with the words TWITTER Link

Comment: Are you trying to remove the `[url]` as well?

Comment: @sln Yup exactly!  So I want to remove the [url] and only match whats inside the url (if its a twitter link)

Comment: Really? `\S+` gets you there. Not in reality.

Comment: @Mark please use my Shortcode library, it will help you do everything related to shortcodes: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `preg_replace` code:

```
$re = '~\[url\]https?://twitter\.com/\S+\[/url\]~'; 
$str = "Blah blah blah [url]https://twitter.com/NBCBlacklist/status/776165827104026624[/url] blah blah"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, "TWITTER Link", $str);

//=> Blah blah blah TWITTER Link blah blah
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jA0nB6/3)

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the url tags you can use something like this

Find:

`'/\[url\](https?:\/\/twitter\.com\/(?:\#!\/)?\w+\/status(?:es)?\/(?:\d+))\[\/url\]/'`

Replace:  `'TWITTER Link $1'`

---

If the tags might not exist, you'd use a branch reset. This

Find:

`'/(?|\[url\]((?&twit))\[\/url\]|((?&twit)))(?(DEFINE)(?<twit>https?:\/\/twitter\.com\/(?:\#!\/)?\w+\/status(?:es)?\/(?:\d+)))/'`

Replace:  `'TWITTER Link $1'`

Expanded

```
 (?|
      \[url\]
      ( (?&twit) )                  # (1)
      \[/url\]
   |  
      ( (?&twit) )                  # (1)
 )
 (?(DEFINE)
      (?<twit>                      # (2 start)
           https?://twitter\.com/
           (?: \#!/ )?
           \w+ /status
           (?: es )?
           /
           (?: \d+ )
      )                             # (2 end)
 )
```